# Move delete button on a comment to top-right corner like it is on StackExchange?

Tags: feature-request, comments, design, user-interface

I really love the placement of the SE comment delete button:

[image]

or the SO style:

[image]

However I like the rounded button on SO better the SE's.

Comment: that _would_ take up less space than the current blocky "Ask Question" button....

Answer (score 1):

Although I like the idea of the SO style, I'm not sure that it is a feature that is needed. I like the asthetics of the red X; however, I don't see any other value in the modification.

Comment: I agree this is totally cosmetic, and while yes, this is a programming website and programmers don't care about design (paraphrasing Jeff in one of the podcasts) I think this should (at the very least) be implemented in all new SE 2.0 sites.